# How to use interface as a method parameter but still access non-interface methods?

Tags: c#, oop

I've spent hours trying to find a way to implement this and so far I haven't found a good solution, so I'm hoping someone could please help point me in the right direction.

I currently have a C# Winforms project that has an abstract base class with several child classes.  Most of the methods are the same but each child class has a few additional methods specific to it.

I want to be able to declare a type of the class being used once and pass that type to all my other methods without having to manually check the type everywhere by going "If Class Type=A Do This Else If Class Type=B Do That, and so on".

The problem is that I need to pass the base class or interface to accomplish this.  However, by doing so it means I can no longer access the properties or methods specific to the child classes and I don't know how to fix/workaround this.

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

**Interface and Class Structure**

```
public interface IAnimal
    {
        string NameOfAnimal { get; set; }

        void Eat();
    }

public abstract class Animal : IAnimal
    {
        public abstract string NameOfAnimal { get; set; }

        public abstract void Eat();
    }

public class Bird : Animal
{
    public Bird()
    {
        NameOfAnimal = "Bob the Bird";
        NumberOfFeathers = 100;
    }

    // Interface members
    public override string NameOfAnimal { get; set; }

    public override void Eat()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Eating like a Bird");
    }

    // Bird specific properties and methods
    public int NumberOfFeathers { get; protected set; }
    public string SomeOtherBirdSpecificProperty { get; protected set; }

    public void Fly()
    {
        // Fly like a bird
    }
}

public class Fish : Animal
{
    public Fish()
    {
        NameOfAnimal = "Jill the Fish";
        DoesFishHaveSharpTeeth = true;
    }

    // Interface members
    public override string NameOfAnimal { get; set; }

    public override void Eat()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Eating like a Fish");
    }

    // Fish specific properties
    public bool DoesFishHaveSharpTeeth { get; protected set; }
    public string SomeOtherFishSpecificProperty { get; protected set; }
}
```

**Main Form Code**

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IAnimal myCustomAnimal = null;
        string animalTheUserSelected = "Bird";

        // Only want to manually specify this once
        switch (animalTheUserSelected)
        {
            case "Bird":
                myCustomAnimal = new Bird();
                break;

            case "Fish":
                myCustomAnimal = new Fish();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        DoSomethingWithACustomAnimal(myCustomAnimal);
    }

    private void DoSomethingWithACustomAnimal(IAnimal myAnimal)
    {
        // This works fine
        MessageBox.Show(myAnimal.NameOfAnimal);
        myAnimal.Eat();

        // This doesn't work
        MessageBox.Show(myAnimal.NumberOfFeathers);
        myAnimal.Fly();
    }
```

I understand why I'm having that issue in the main form code... the compiler doesn't know which type of animal is being passed to it yet so it doesn't know what to show.  However, I don't know what I should do to fix this.

I've tried:

- Putting all the animal-specific properties in the interface.  This works but violates several OOP principles.  A fish doesn't have feathers, etc. so these specific properties don't belong there.
- Manually checking the type everywhere by going something like "If Type=Fish do abc Else If Type=Bird do def".  This also works but violates the DRY principle because I'm repeating myself everywhere.  Also with a lot of methods using animals, this will be a nightmare to maintain in the future.
- Explicitly casting IAnimal to a specific animal like ((Bird)myCustomAnimal).NumberOfFeathers.  This also works but I don't know what cast to use at compile-time.  This won't be known until the user selects an animal at run-time.

So I'm just wondering how I can solve this issue?

More specifically, I'm wondering how I can re-design the above code so that I can both:

A) Explicitly declare a type of animal only once and pass that type everywhere (without having to do lots of manual checks in every method to see what type it is before doing something with it)

and also

B) Somehow still have a way to manually access the animal-specific properties like someBird.NumberOfFeathers when I need to.

Any ideas?

Comment: You really need to think about what your structure is actually supposed to be. When you get into problems like this it pays to sit down and think about what the *essential* properties are and how they need to be group together in one or more interfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on exactly what you are trying to do and what you are hoping to achieve. All the things you've tried so far are possible approaches, but without more context it's hard to give a general answer. It depends on what the right level of abstraction is for what you are trying to do.

One thing to remember is that you can have a class implement as many interfaces as you need. So you could do something like:

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    string NameOfAnimal { get; set; }
    void Eat();
}

public interface IFly
{
    void Fly();
}

public interface IHaveFeathers
{
    int NumberOfFeathers { get; set; }
}
```

Then you `Bird` class can be:

```
public Bird : Animal, IFly, IHaveFeathers
{
    // implementation
}
```

And now in a method you can do something like:

```
private void DoSomethingWithACustomAnimal(IAnimal myAnimal)
{
    // This works fine
    MessageBox.Show(myAnimal.NameOfAnimal);
    myAnimal.Eat();

    var feathered = myAnimal as IHaveFeathers;
    if (feathered != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(feathered.NumberOfFeathers);
    }

    var flier = myAnimal as IFly;
    if (flier != null)
    {
        flier.Fly();
    }
}
```

The other thing to think about is how to abstract what you need to a higher level. So you need to `Fly`, but why? What happens with the `Animal` that can't fly? By `Fly` are you really just trying to `Move`? Then perhaps you could do:

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    string NameOfAnimal { get; set; }
    void Eat();
    void Move();
}
```

And in your `Bird` you can do this:

```
public Bird : Animal, IFly, IHaveFeathers
{
    public override void Move()
    {
        Fly();
    }

    public void Fly()
    {
        // your flying implementation
    }
    // rest of the implementation...
}
```

Comment: This ended up solving it for me.  I can't post my updated code here.  But the key was your other comments about thinking about the structure.  I ended up refactoring my design several times and I now have most of the animal specific stuff in that animals class.  I also did my interfaces like IAnimalSettings and then specific ones like IBirdSettings : IAnimalSettings, etc.  Even further, I did what you said so the IAnimal class has public methods like TakeAction(), Move(), etc. and then each animal overrides them.  So Bird Flys(), Fish Swims(), Bee TakeAction() becomes MakeHoney(), etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

One solution would be to use the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) to define the operations you want to perform on your animal instances.

First you would define a visitor interface which provides a method for each type of animal you have in your hierarchy.

```
public interface IAnimalVisitor
{
    void VisitBird(Bird bird);
    void VisitFish(Fish fish);
}
```

And then you would need to modify your animal classes and interfaces to include a method which accepts a visitor, like so:

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    string NameOfAnimal { get; set; }
    void Accept(IAnimalVisitor visitor);
}
```

Your actual animal classes now look something like this:

```
public class Bird : IAnimal
{
    public Bird()
    {
        NameOfAnimal = "Bob the Bird";
        NumberOfFeathers = 100;
    }

    public string NameOfAnimal { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfFeathers { get; protected set; }

    public void Accept (IAnimalVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.VisitBird(this);
    }
}

public class Fish : IAnimal
{
    public Fish()
    {
        NameOfAnimal = "Jill the Fish";
        DoesFishHaveSharpTeeth = true;
    }

    public string NameOfAnimal { get; set; }
    public bool DoesFishHaveSharpTeeth { get; protected set; }

    public void Accept (IAnimalVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.VisitFish(this);
    }
}
```

Now for anything you want to do with each of your animals you will need to define an implementation of the `IAnimalVisitor` interface. In your example you displayed message boxes that showed information about the animal so an implementation of the `IAnimalVisitor` interface that does that could look like this:

```
public class AnimalMessageBoxes : IAnimalVisitor
{
    private void VisitAnimal(IAnimal animal)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(animal.NameOfAnimal);
    }

    public void VisitBird(Bird bird)
    {
        visitAnimal(bird);
        MessageBox.Show(bird.NumberOfFeathers);
    }

    public void VisitFish(Fish fish)
    {
        visitAnimal(fish);
        MessageBox.Show(fish.DoesFishHaveSharpTeeth);
    }
}
```

Now you just need to pass your visitor to your animal and the correct information will be displayed. Your event handling code now looks something like this:

```
string animalTheUserSelected = "Bird";
IAnimal myCustomAnimal = null;

switch (animalTheUserSelected)
{
    case "Bird":
        myCustomAnimal = new Bird();
            break;

    case "Fish":
        myCustomAnimal = new Fish();
            break;

     default:
        break;
}

AnimalMessageBoxes msgBoxes = new AnimalMessageBoxes();
myCustomAnimal.Accept(msgBoxes);
```

If you want to do something else to your animal instances (save them to a file, generate a UI, play sounds...) you just need to define a new `IAnimalVisitor` implementation that provides your desired behaviour.

For the sake of balance I will say that this might not be an appropriate design as it adds some additional complexity; each 'operation' requires you to implement a visitor and the addition of another animal to your hierarchy requires you to update your visitor interface and all of it's implementations to account for the new case.

Depending on your point of view this can be either good or bad. Some consider the points above to be bad and a reason to avoid the visitor pattern and to use the other methods already suggested. Others (like me) consider the points above to be a good thing; your code will now only compile when you provide an implementation for each animal in your hierarchy and your operations are separated into small, dedicated classes.

My suggestion would be to try the SSCCE I have provided and research the visitor pattern further to decide if this solution is acceptable for your requirements.

Comment: I love your example.  I did play with it and it seems to be a very powerful pattern.  However it also increases the complexity.  In my case, by taking some of the other advice and refactoring properly, I was able to eliminate the need to do a lot of casting and so the extra complexity didn't seem worth it.  I've saved this for future reference so I can use it on more complex projects :)

Answer (score 2):

I understand, what you are trying to achive, but your approach is just wrong.

Think it this way: does your "Main" class/form realy need to know if there is a bird or a dog? The answer is "NO". There are some common properties which you exposed via an interface (i suggest using a base class here!). Everything else is specific to the given animal. The easiest approach is extending your interface with a DoAnimalSpecificStuff() method - which would perform the specific opperations.

When it comes to presentation, you should take a look at the MVP and MVVM Patterns.

P.S. use a Factory Pattern for animal creation!

Comment: Your suggestion is fine for methods that change the state of the animal but may violate best practices if you want to do something such as saving animal information to a file, displaying it in message boxes or sending an email. IMHO it would be inappropriate for the `Animal` class to have `Save`, `Display` and `SendEmail` methods. If you use a presentation (or other) pattern to wrap the `Animal` class to provide these features you end up with the same problem of having to use if-statements and casts to perform an operation on arbitrary animal objects.

Comment: This is wrong. Displaying: View - animal specific (you cant Show a cat and pretend it beeing a dog). Saving: IAnimal Based - serialization (for saving) is specific (ISerializable). Same goes for Mail and other stuff. Also: never use 'if' Statements, go for AOP or generics when it comes to types

Comment: A variable of type `Animal` could reference either a `Cat` or a `Dog`. If you want to perform an operation specific to the actual runtime type of animal being referenced you can use polymorphism and provide a method in the `Animal` base class to perform the operation (as you have suggested) or you can provide a separate class to perform the operation. If the method does something that the animal class should know nothing about such as generate a UI or send an email then the method does not belong on the `Animal` class and should be placed in a separate class.

Comment: continued: If the method is placed in a separate class and has to operate on **any** animal type then you will have to resort to using casts and if-statements in order to access subclass specific methods and properties. You could provide overloaded methods that accept `Animal` subclasses as arguments but you are just moving the problem of determining the type of the animal to the code that invokes the method. The only way to eliminate the casts *in these cases* is to use the visitor pattern as I have suggested. As noted in my post though the pattern does come with it's own problems.

Comment: A class does not have to be plain and pure. Classes are not meant to be pure containers. They may contain aspects and even behaviours. Those can be placed in base classes or be exposed via interfaces. Utilize services (basing on those patterns) to bring the concrete use-case into life.

Comment: PS: the answer provided by Matt demonstrates what I described :)

Comment: You all make good points.  My biggest problem was not grouping my classes right so the main form was trying to do bird specific and dog specific stuff.  Now that I've refactored that it works much simpler.  I am using a factory to make the animals now as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly cast the `IAnimal` object to specific type, if you want to access specific properties/methods.

You can use `as` operator and then check if the cast was successful like:

```
Bird b = myAnimal as Bird;
if(b != null)
{
     MessageBox.Show(b.NumberOfFeathers);
}
```

Comment: Ooh nice idea.  I see what you're meaning but my only concern is that it will be a lot of repetitive coding.  If I have lots of animals and lots of methods that use them, I'll have to keep checking them everywhere to see what I can and can't do with each animal object.  Do you know of any other ways I could setup my code so I won't have this issue?  I'm not sure if there's any design patterns or anything I could read up on that might give me a better way of designing this?

Comment: the issue is that you are combining similar properties, and you still want to to access unique properties. There is no other way, to work with specific properties, you have to use specific type and not a base type.

Comment: @Calcolat `If I have lots of animals and lots of methods that use them,`, and that's your problem. Why do you have lots of animals and lots of methods that exist in some other class? Can you put the pieces that need to access the `Bird` (rather than `Animal`) properties and method *inside* `Bird`? Don't expose them if they don't need to be exposed.